# Desable Athurization on one controller in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a website that write athentication for admin panel but when I run the project it shows login page, i want to show home page of site and if user enter admin panel url go to login page.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms defaultUrl="~/Admin/Index" loginUrl="~/Acount/Login"
       cookieless="UseCookies"
   protection="All"
   slidingExpiration="true"
   timeout="20">
</forms>
  </authentication>
 <authorization >
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="~/Site/home"> 
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

what should I do? It Also shows login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in your action or controller example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController:Controller
{
     [AllowAnonymous]
      public ActionResult Home() 
      {
        //
      }
}
```

this will allow access to certain controller / actions.

Answer (score 0):

maybe changing the information on RouteConfig.cs

example :

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Procesos", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I checked that. It was true.